# Some of wordpress posts getting err_too_many_redirects

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

when ı checked my wordpress https website today i found some redirecting errors.

I never created those redirection on my side.

1. https://www.estambul.net/sitios-de-interes/mezquita-azul/
2. https://www.estambul.net/sitios-de-interes/santa-sofia/

these two posts redirected to

****/sitios-de-interes/museo-arqueologico-de-estambul/

and this

****/sitios-de-interes/museo-arqueologico-de-estambul/

redirected to

****/sitios-de-interes/santa-sofia/

all these creates an infinite loop.

here you can see my htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header always set Strict-Transport-Security 'max-age=31536000' env=HTTPS
</IfModule>
# END rlrssslReallySimpleSSL
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Where it comes this problem please help.

Other posts doesnt have the same problem.

Comment: I have found out that when i cange url slug it solves the problem. what can be a problem with slugs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After two days of working we have solved the issue by removing old slugs of these posts from postmeta in mysql.

Old slugs were saved with wrong post ids. That was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please check those post's content if there is any script which causing this redirection.